# Triple boot, customize grub (Windows 8.1, Ubuntu, Zorin)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a Win8.1 laptop. I installed Ubuntu, and had the installer put it on it's own 50MB partition. I installed Zorin and did the same.

I installed Grub Customizer on Zorin, and changed the list order.

When I rebooted, The order wasn't what I set it to.

So, I installed Grub Customizer on Ubuntu and did the same thing.

The header says "GNU Grub Version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7"

The list items are in this order:

- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
- Advanced Options for Zorin
- Advanced Options for Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda6)
- System Settings
- Zorin
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda6)

When I go back into Zorin and launch Grub Customizer, it agrees with this order. If I edit the order, save and re-boot, the order reverts to this.

I set my preferred order in Ubuntu and it seems to save, and it worked before I installed Zorin. But, the actual boot menu does not reflect the changes. If you follow my shorthand, I want the boot order to be W,Z,U,AOZ,AOU,SYSTEM. I also set a background image for GRUB in both customizers and neither one made the image display.

How can I verify which distro is actually in control of grub? How can I customize the boot order and appearance?

side note: All 3 OSs load correctly when selected.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info And Summary report will not show the grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu, post that also, its UUID should be the UUID of your Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is **THE** solution, or even the *right* solution, but my solution to the settings not being saved was to use "File->Install to MBR..."

My solution to the background image was to replace it with a PNG.

I did this in Zorin, not Ubuntu. My **GUESS** is that the latest installed OS has the preference, and writing to the MBR removes any doubt or ambiguity.